# Fortran direct access

Tags: fortran

I am looking for a way to access a specific column and row from an external file (txt or csv for example. Idealy it would be from an excel sheet.) using fortran.
Example: in my txt file is a matrix:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

I only want to access the "6".

I know that there are different access methods.
Is it right that i can't access a specific column and row using the default "sequential access method"?
I know there are two other methods, "direct access" and "stream", but i can't find good documentation online. 
Using the direct access method, i don't know the right statements or arguments for the "read" funktion to access a specific entry from a file.

It would be of huge help if somebody could advise a good documentation.

Comment: There is loads of documentation online. However, if you have a typical text file, both stream and direct access, although available for formatted access, will be of little use. If all the lines had the same length one would have some hope.

Comment: Like @VladimirF pointed out, this depends on how 'standardized' the file you are reading is. Take a look at http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Stream+Input+Output for some information on records and streams. Perhaps you can isolate a specific line (record) and overwrite it as required.

Comment: Otherwise the normal way is to read the whole file into an array and work with that array. There are many questions and answers about how to do that here at Stack Overflow.